# Apache2 VirtualHost SSL config issues

Tags: ssl, debian, apache2, virtualhost, nextcloud

Debian 10 / Apache2 -

GOAL: redirect all web traffic to VPS server to SSL. I have 2 sites hosted: bjmurrey.com and nextcloud.bjmurrey.com. I have 1 IP address.

PROBLEM: I can't for the life of me find a way to make this work. I have tried 1000 suggestions posted here and elsewhere with no success. The closest I get is everything redirects to https://bjmurrey.com when typing in nextcloud.bjmurrey.com. I am also a novice at this so please be kind.

I have a default.conf that looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.bjmurrey.com
    ServerAlias bjmurrey.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/blog
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    Redirect permanent / https://bjmurrey.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName nextcloud.bjmurrey.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud
    ServerAlias nextcloud.bjmurrey.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    Redirect permanent / https://nextcloud.bjmurrey.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

I have a default-ssl.conf that looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost bjmurrey.com:443> 
   ServerName bjmurrey.com 
   ServerAlias www.bjmurrey.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/blog
   SSLEngine on 
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/bjmurrey.com/fullchain.pem
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/bjmurrey.com/privkey.pem
   Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost nextcloud.bjmurrey.com:443>
    ServerName nextcloud.bjmurrey.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud
    ServerAlias nextcloud.bjmurrey.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/nextcloud.bjmurrey.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/nextcloud.bjmurrey.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

bjmurrey.com is in var/www/blog and nextcloud.bjmurrey.com in the var/www/nextcloud directories.

I have my DNS records www and nextcloud both pointed to same IP. I only have 1 IP available. This is a very low traffic site.
I have done all kinds of things like just have the default virtual host redirect to only nextcloud and removed all mention of the www site and it still redirects to bjmurrey.com, or redirects with an SSL error saying that nextcloud can't be loaded because the ssl is for bjmurrey.com only. As you can see I have made certs with letsencrypt for both bjmurrey.com and nextcloud.bjmurrey.com.

I'm about to yank all my hair out in frustration, so I know I've tapped out all my knowledge here. Help!

Comment: I assume both host, inside the server, resolve to the same address). Use the both *:443 and reverser the order (put first the ServerName nextcloud.xxxx.xxx. For the redirections in port 80, I have to think a little more..

Comment: I did try to reverse them - with the same results. :( Thanks for the tip though! :) 
Perhaps it's something with the SSL cert for both sites being in the same domain (bjmurrey.com & nextcloud.bjmurrey.com) ?

Comment: Added an answer. Please, double check you are using *:80 and *:443.

Answer (score 0):

I have retested with http and is working for me.

Both addresses `mydomain.myhost.example.com` and `myhost.example.com`  resolve to the same IP.

This is my configuration file

```
ServerName example.com

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mydomain.myhost.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myhost.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/myhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Tested in Ubuntu 20.04.1, Apache 2.4